Log4j2 does not persist with JDBC appender
I have a small app project that stores its state in an SQLite database. I'm using Maven and Spring Boot. I haven't had any issues with entity persistence (I'm using Spring Data JPA), but I can't get log4j2 to persist in the database. The database consists of a file named data.db located in the same project folder. When I run the project, I do so from this folder after executing mvn clean package.
My configuration file (log4j2.xml), which is stored in the resources folder (src/main/resources), is as follows. I assumed that since it’s an embedded database, pooling wouldn't matter, so I used the simplest configuration option, which is not recommended for large databases. I’ve tried to follow the documentation, but I might have made a mistake:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" name="config">
    <Appenders>
        <JDBC name="database" tableName="APPLICATION_LOG">
            <DriverManager>
                <connectionString>jdbc:sqlite:data.db</connectionString>
                <driverClassName>org.sqlite.JDBC</driverClassName>
            </DriverManager>
            <Column name="EVENT_ID" literal="NULL" />
            <Column name="EVENT_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="LEVEL" pattern="%level" />
            <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" />
            <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" />
            <Column name="THROWABLE" pattern="%ex{full}" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="database" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

The version of Java I'm using is 21, and the JVM is Semeru for Windows.
In the POM, I’ve included the following dependencies related to JDBC, SQLite, and Log4j2:
        <!--log4j api-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--log4j core engine-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--sqlite jdbc driver-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--community-dialects-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Versions are not specified because I understand that the parent POM, provided by Spring Initializr, has them already configured:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

The schema of the table where the logs are supposed to be persisted is as follows:
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION_LOG ( EVENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, LEVEL TEXT, LOGGER TEXT, MESSAGE TEXT, THROWABLE TEXT);

The app works, but I can't get the logs to persist. Could it be that I'm misconfiguring something? Is something missing?
I forgot to say, there are no errors in the logs.
This is my application.properties file:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:./data.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.datasource.platform=sqlite
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.batch.job.enabled=false

I am trying to have all the logs saved to the database in the APPLICATION_LOG table.

I suspect that this is a problem with the file name in the JDBC connection string "jdbc:sqlite:data.db".  You have used a relative path ("data.db"), and my bet would be that it  is resolving differently to what you expect.  1) Use an absolute path.  2) Don't put the Sqlite DB inside your project directory.  (The project directory won't exist when you deploy the code.)

(1) Answer is here: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/discussions/2911  (2) The root cause is that Log4j will use setNString to write by default, but SQLite does not accept it.  (3) Therefore, the writing will fail. There are two modification methods to make Log4j use setString or setObject to write SQLIte. (4) ppkarwasz provide the answer.
